# iScroll 4 and highcharts compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, iscroll4

i'm trying to use the highcharts library with iScroll4. You can see a complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pn5SW/1/).
The problem as you can see is that the outer div's width is getting ignored by the browser and the iScroll div apparently doesn't show at all.
What i want to achieve is having a graph with width=1000px inside a container with width=200px. Of course i want the graph to be scrollable (horizontally) so that i can see all the graph and not only the left part. To do this, i want to use iScroll4 as i already used it inside the same project for another feature.
Can you point out where the problem is in my code?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/pn5SW/5/

you have to set overflow-x: for div. try to scroll using the space below  #charts div (portrait mode).

Highcharts to use touch events of the ios, they prevent the default events, you may try this alternative solution like this. http://jsfiddle.net/HXUmK/126/

Comment: This is not what i want. I want to scroll the chart itself. Btw, thanks for trying